# Configuration compile and runtime for gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I set up a classpath for my jar reference inside a jar.('classpath: 'wee.jar'), but apparently, I also need to type the following in my jar task

```
from {
    configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
    configurations.runtime.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
```

Can Someone explain to me what does from, configuration.compile.collect, runtime, and isDirectory and zipTree do? I look up google, but couldn't find any answer. I'm really new to gradle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starters, you do not need both `configurations.compile` and `configurations.runtime`. In gradle, the compile time dependencies are already included in runtime config automatically - which makes compile a subset of runtime. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you'll only need one or the other. So let's take this snippet:

```
configurations.compile.collect {
    it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
}
```

A configuration represents a collection of artifacts and their dependencies. `compile` and `runtime` are among configs that are added by the java plugin. `collect` is groovy for: do the following operation for every element of a collection and return the result as a set. So effectively the line of code translates to - for all dependencies declared in `configurations.compile`, do the following and return the results as a set.

`it` is groovy shorthand for iterator - so it represents each element of the aforesaid collection.

```
if `it` is a directory
    include it as is, 
else
    unpack the file and then include it
```

([See zipTree reference here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#zipTree(java.lang.Object)))

Putting the whole thing together, the code is taking all compile time dependency directories and all unpacked compile time jars and including that into the jar you're building.